# C - \r does not work in printf() with nanosleep()

Tags: c, printf

I was trying to use the '\r' character to write over the previous line; however, when used in conjunction with nanosleep(), the program does not output until the end. Here is a code example:

```
int i;
struct timespec t = {1, 0};
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    nanosleep(&t, NULL);
    printf('\ri: %d', i);
}
```

This will wait for 10 seconds, and then print out `i: 9`. I would like it to show the updates, not just the end. I'm not sure if the line is being flushed or something?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read the documentation for `fflush`.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: `'\ri: %d'` is a multibyte character constant ; perhaps you meant `"\ri: %d"`

Comment: @M.M Yes, that is what I meant. The code I was running had double quotes, I mistyped it here when creating the post.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was asking specifically if I can do this with `printf()` and if not, why I could not.

Comment: @mkel23 Read your question again. You didn't ask what you think you asked. As I read the question, you asked for an explanation for the behavior you were observing. And nowhere do I see any indication that you're trying to get `printf` specifically to do something.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are correct, my apologies. Had I been clear and concise in the body of my post, there would be less confusion. It is clear now that it is not possible and that I need to use `fflush()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is caching your line until the char \n (newline) appears. You can use "fflush" to explicitly write the content to screen.
Maybe there is a little impact on performance.